# VS code revert catch statement's parameter error: any or error: unknown to error only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-18, typescript4.0

When try to run react app (react18 and typescirpt 4)

There is a terminal error

**TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'unknown'.**

```
try {


} catch (error: any) {
    // do something
}

try {


} catch (error: unknown) {
    // do something
}

try {


} catch (error: CustError) {
    // do something
}
```

VScode will instantly revert to on save

```
try {


} catch (error) {
    // do something
}
```

Is it a way to get around with this?

Comment: that's weird and it sounds like a bug. I don't think this is intended behaviour. You might additionally want to file a bug report (use the `Help: Report Issue` command in the command palette). Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: what action are you taking that results in the terminal error? I.e. how are you running tsc? And what version of TypeScript _exactly_ are you compiling with? (check `npm list typescript`).

Comment: Also N.B. that `err: unknown` is the correct annotation for the value in a `catch` block: there is *no guarantee* that value is an instanceof Error. You can literally `throw` *anything* in Javascript.